# Better way to extract html table to dictionary using beautifulsoup in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I am scraping HTML pages. Part of the page has a table which has acts and sections of those acts mentioned in table format. For some other project I need to convert them to Dictionary. The key values are previously set (in the other project). I want to use the same key values for the dictionary and then replace corresponding sections with each new input. The code I have designed works but I am looking for better way to write it. Presently the code looks quite lengthy. The code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs, NavigableString

openFile = open('/some path/samplePage.html')
soup = bs(openFile, 'html.parser')

acts = soup.select('#act_table td:nth-of-type(1)')
sections = soup.select('#act_table td:nth-of-type(2)')
dictionary = {}


ipc = 'indian penal code'
poa = 'prevention of atrocities'
pcso = 'protection of children from sexual'
pcr = 'protection of civil rights'


if len(acts) < 1:
    print('no act mentioned')
elif len(acts) < 2:
    act1 = tuple(acts[0].contents)
    sections1 = tuple(sections[0].contents)
elif len(acts) < 3:
    act1 = tuple(acts[0].contents)
    sections1 = tuple(sections[0].contents)
    act2 = tuple(acts[1].contents)
    sections2 = tuple(sections[1].contents)
elif len(acts) < 4:
    act1 = tuple(acts[0].contents)
    sections1 = tuple(sections[0].contents)
    act2 = tuple(acts[1].contents)
    sections2 = tuple(sections[1].contents)
    act3 = tuple(acts[2].contents)
    sections3 = tuple(sections[2].contents)
elif len(acts) < 5:
    act1 = tuple(acts[0].contents)
    sections1 = tuple(sections[0].contents)
    act2 = tuple(acts[1].contents)
    sections2 = tuple(sections[1].contents)
    act3 = tuple(acts[2].contents)
    sections3 = tuple(sections[2].contents)
    act4 = tuple(acts[3].contents)
    sections4 = tuple(sections[3].contents)
else:
    act1 = tuple(acts[0].contents)
    sections1 = tuple(sections[0].contents)
    act2 = tuple(acts[1].contents)
    sections2 = tuple(sections[1].contents)
    act3 = tuple(acts[2].contents)
    sections3 = tuple(sections[2].contents)
    act4 = tuple(acts[3].contents)
    sections4 = tuple(sections[3].contents)
    act5 = tuple(acts[4].contents)


if len(acts) == 0:
    pass
# for first act in list
elif len(acts) == 1:
    if ipc in str(act1).lower():
        dictionary['IPC'] = sections1
    elif poa in str(act1).lower():
        dictionary['PoA'] = sections1
    elif pcso in str(act1).lower():
        dictionary['PCSO'] = sections1
    elif pcr in str(act1).lower():
        dictionary['PCR'] = sections1
    else:
        dictionary['Any Other Act'] = str(act1).lower()
    print(dictionary)

# for 2nd act in list
elif len(acts) == 2:
    if ipc in str(act1).lower():
        dictionary['IPC'] = sections1
    elif poa in str(act1).lower():
        dictionary['PoA'] = sections1
    elif pcso in str(act1).lower():
        dictionary['PCSO'] = sections1
    else:
        dictionary['Any Other Act'] = str(act1).lower()
    if ipc in str(act2).lower():
        dictionary['IPC'] = sections2
    elif poa in str(act2).lower():
        dictionary['PoA'] = sections2
    elif pcso in str(act2).lower():
        dictionary['PCSO'] = sections2
    else:
        dictionary['Any Other Act'] = act2
    print(dictionary)
# for 3rd act in list
elif len(acts) == 3:
    if ipc in str(act1).lower():
        dictionary['IPC'] = sections1
    elif poa in str(act1).lower():
        dictionary['PoA'] = sections1
    elif pcso in str(act1).lower():
        dictionary['PCSO'] = sections1
    elif pcr in str(act1).lower():
        dictionary['PCR'] = sections1
    else:
        dictionary['Any Other Act'] = str(act1).lower()
    if ipc in str(act2).lower():
        dictionary['IPC'] = sections2
    elif poa in str(act2).lower():
        dictionary['PoA'] = sections2
    elif pcso in str(act2).lower():
        dictionary['PCSO'] = sections2
    elif pcr in str(act2).lower():
        dictionary['PCR'] = sections2
    else:
        dictionary['Any Other Act'] = act2
    #for 3rd option
    if ipc in str(act3).lower():
        dictionary['IPC'] = sections3
    elif poa in str(act3).lower():
        dictionary['PoA'] = sections3
    elif pcso in str(act3).lower():
        dictionary['PCSO'] = sections3
    elif pcr in str(act3).lower():
        dictionary['PCR'] = sections3
    else:
        dictionary['Any Other Act'] = act3
    print(dictionary)
    # for 4th act in list
elif len(acts) == 4:
    if ipc in str(act1).lower():
        dictionary['IPC'] = sections1
    elif poa in str(act1).lower():
        dictionary['PoA'] = sections1
    elif pcso in str(act1).lower():
        dictionary['PCSO'] = sections1
    elif pcr in str(act1).lower():
        dictionary['PCR'] = sections1
    else:
        dictionary['Any Other Act'] = str(act1).lower()
    if ipc in str(act2).lower():
        dictionary['IPC'] = sections2
    elif poa in str(act2).lower():
        dictionary['PoA'] = sections2
    elif pcso in str(act2).lower():
        dictionary['PCSO'] = sections2
    elif pcr in str(act2).lower():
        dictionary['PCR'] = sections2
    else:
        dictionary['Any Other Act'] = act2
    # for 3rd option
    if ipc in str(act3).lower():
        dictionary['IPC'] = sections3
    elif poa in str(act3).lower():
        dictionary['PoA'] = sections3
    elif pcso in str(act3).lower():
        dictionary['PCSO'] = sections3
    elif pcr in str(act3).lower():
        dictionary['PCR'] = sections3
    else:
        dictionary['Any Other Act'] = act3
    # 4th Option
    if ipc in str(act4).lower():
        dictionary['IPC'] = sections4
    elif poa in str(act4).lower():
        dictionary['PoA'] = sections4
    elif pcso in str(act4).lower():
        dictionary['PCSO'] = sections4
    elif pcr in str(act4).lower():
        dictionary['PCR'] = sections4
    else:
        dictionary['Any Other Act'] = act4
elif len(acts) == 5:
    if ipc in str(act1).lower():
        dictionary['IPC'] = sections1
    elif poa in str(act1).lower():
        dictionary['PoA'] = sections1
    elif pcso in str(act1).lower():
        dictionary['PCSO'] = sections1
    elif pcr in str(act1).lower():
        dictionary['PCR'] = sections1
    else:
        dictionary['Any Other Act'] = str(act1).lower()
    if ipc in str(act2).lower():
        dictionary['IPC'] = sections2
    elif poa in str(act2).lower():
        dictionary['PoA'] = sections2
    elif pcso in str(act2).lower():
        dictionary['PCSO'] = sections2
    elif pcr in str(act2).lower():
        dictionary['PCR'] = sections2
    else:
        dictionary['Any Other Act'] = act2
    # for 3rd option
    if ipc in str(act3).lower():
        dictionary['IPC'] = sections3
    elif poa in str(act3).lower():
        dictionary['PoA'] = sections3
    elif pcso in str(act3).lower():
        dictionary['PCSO'] = sections3
    elif pcr in str(act3).lower():
        dictionary['PCR'] = sections3
    else:
        dictionary['Any Other Act'] = act3
    # 4th Option
    if ipc in str(act4).lower():
        dictionary['IPC'] = sections4
    elif poa in str(act4).lower():
        dictionary['PoA'] = sections4
    elif pcso in str(act4).lower():
        dictionary['PCSO'] = sections4
    elif pcr in str(act4).lower():
        dictionary['PCR'] = sections4
    else:
        dictionary['Any Other Act'] = act4
print(dictionary)
```

The HTML code of one of the files is here:

[link to the source code](https://github.com/sangharshbyss/EcourtsData/blob/master/samplePage.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're repeating *a lot* of code in this program. It seems like as the length of `acts` gets larger, you expand to analyzing acts. This is a perfect opportunity for a loop. What I did was get the length of `acts` at the very beginning, then base my loop of that. Since you always want the last element you find, this works great. I'll explain below what I did in places that seem confusing.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

site_file = open('samplePage.html')
soup = bs(site_file, 'html.parser')

acts = soup.select('#act_table td:nth-of-type(1)')
sections = soup.select('#act_table td:nth-of-type(2)')
dictionary = {}

ipc = 'indian penal code'
poa = 'prevention of atrocities'
pcso = 'protection of children from sexual'
pcr = 'protection of civil rights'

code_dict = {ipc: "IPC", poa: "PoA", pcso: "PCSO", pcr: "PCR"}

ACT_LENGTH = len(acts) if len(acts) < 5 else 5

if len(acts) > 0:
    collected_acts = [tuple(acts[i].contents) for i in range(ACT_LENGTH)]
    collected_sections = [tuple(sections[i].contents) for i in range(ACT_LENGTH)]
else:
    print("No Act Mentioned")

for i in range(ACT_LENGTH):
    act = str(collected_acts[i]).lower()
    accepted = [code_dict[code] for code in code_dict.keys() if code in act]
    for code in accepted:
        dictionary[code] = collected_sections[i]
print(dictionary)

site_file.close()
```

## ACT_LENGTH

The reason `ACT_LENGTH` is written that way is because once the length of `acts` is bigger than `5`, you only go a set amount instead of the length. Because of this, we want to only loop up to **four** because of how range works. (`range(INCLUSIVE, EXCLUSIVE)`).

## Use lists!

Instead of defining new variables based on how big `acts` is, we can simply use list comprehension to create a list of variables as big as `acts`.

## Shorten your code with loops

Instead of checking each individual key with its own `if` statement, we can organize all the "accepted", meaning codes that are in `act`, into a list and loop through those to add to the dictionary.

## File handling

It's always good practice to close a file once you're done using it.

Comment: Thanks. I haven't tried it. Please give me some time and I will get back to you.

Comment: This is "the answer", I was wondering how can I use the loop, but the list comprehension solved the issue. Especially two variables the code_dict and accepted are nice idea. Thanks again. I have edited few lines to adjust as per the requirement.